# Firebase - Firestore - how many time will I read documents

Tags: firebase, observable, google-cloud-firestore

With the new Firestore from Firebase, I discovered that I have poor knowledge with Observables.

My problem is the following:

I get some data with db.collection('room').

1. If I don't listen to the observable with a subscription, do I fetch the document? (I think so).
2. For every change in my collection "room", is it considered as a "new document read" by Firestore?
3. If I have duplicated Observables which return db.collection('room') in my app, will I have X calls to the Firestore database or just one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> 1. If I don't listen to the observable with a subscription, do I fetch the document? (I think so).

When you call `var ref = db.collection('room')`, `ref` is not really an observable it is a reference to the `'room'` collection.  Creating this reference does not perform any data reads (from network or disk).

When you call `ref.get()` or `ref.onSnapshot()` then you are fetching the documents from the server.

> 2. For every change in my collection "room", is it considered as a "new document read" by Firestore?

If you are listening to the whole collection (no `where()` or `.orderBy()` clauses) and you have an active `onSnapshot()` listener then yes, you will be charged for a document read operation each time a new document is added, changed, or deleted in the collection.

> 3. If I have duplicated Observables which return db.collection('room') in my app, will I have X calls to the Firestore database or just one?

If you are listening to the same Cloud Firestore data in two places you will only make one call to the server and be charged for the read operations one time.  There's no cost/performance penalty to attaching multiple listeners to one reference.

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer. This is really helpfull!
For the third question: If I define 2 independent observables which call both 
 `db.collection('room').onSnapshot()`, will it be considere as one call or two?

Comment: You will only be actually reading the documents once, we will just notify both observers.

Comment: @SamStern For the second point, when you say you will "you will be charged for a document read operation each time a new document is added...", is this a flat rate charge per each document in the collection? This is to say for example, if I have 5 documents in my collection, and I edit one document in the collection, and I am listening to the entire collection, will I be charged for 5 document reads? Thanks

Comment: @JonnySprouse no, you will be charged 1 document read for the 1 added document if you have an active snapshot listener (<=30m old).

Comment: If am getting the total number of count from a collection, will that be considered as read operation?

Comment: @SamStern what if for #2, a rule is added on the server-side to filter the list of documents sent to the user? say the filter inspects the doc and verifies that a field has the same value as request.auth.uid. Does it still incur a charge for filtering the doc?

Comment: @vinnybad rules are not filters, so that is not possible: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#queries_and_security_rules

Comment: @SamStern the third point is also valid for Firebase realtime DB? db.list('products') having multiple subscriptions?